# Multivariable limit: Proving Limit does not exist, how to choose the best path

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I am given the problem 
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{ y\sin^2{x}}{x^4 + y^2}
$$
I know the first path to choose is either the x-axis or y-axis. This gives the limit of 0.
Now I don't know how to choose the second path to prove that it does not exist.

Please forgive me for the format, I am new and I haven't learned it yet.
Also sorry for my English if it's not properly correct.

Comment: The answers give examples of paths that do this. As for how to find such examples, typically one first tries linear approaches, namely $y = ax$ where $a$ is a constant, and see if the expression is constant that varies with $a.$ If this doesn't work (i.e. you get a constant value for the limit that doesn't vary with $a),$ then try quadratic approaches, namely $y = x^2$ (or more generally, $y = ax^2$ where $a$ is a constant), or cubic approaches, or $n$'th degree approaches (i.e. $y = ax^n$ where both $a$ and $n$ are constants). **(continued)**

Comment: [Here is an example](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/1891/745) where you need to go beyond "polynomial approaches".

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take $y=x^{2}$ and show that the limit is $\frac 1 2$. Use the fact that $\frac {\sin \, x  } x \to 1$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: Oh that makes sense! I forgot about that theorem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x,y)=\frac{y \sin^2 x}{x^4+y^2}$, then compute

$\lim_{x \to 0}f(x,0)$ and $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x,x^2)$.

Consequence ?